# Cell applies extra shadows while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add shadow and to a custom `UITableViewCell`, everything works fine but when I scroll tableview, the cell's shadow will be applied on and on and makes shadow thicker. Here is my code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DriverCell


        //Create space between cells
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.88, green:0.94, blue:0.99, alpha:1.00)
        let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:8, y:10, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 15 , height:150))
        whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
        whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        whiteRoundedView.clipsToBounds = false
        cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
        cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)


        return cell
    }
```

1. Default shadow
2. Extra shadow applied

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UITableViewCell is a reusable view. That means because your cellForRow gets called when you scroll, a shadow will apply at some point to the view again.

For example: Views A, B, C are on screen, when you scroll down and view A gets hidden, view A will be reused and the shadow will be created again for view A.

For your case I will suggest in you DriverCell to add the shadow in the init like this:

```
class DriverCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.88, green:0.94, blue:0.99, alpha:1.00)
    let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:8, y:10, width: frame.size.width - 15 , height:150))
    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    whiteRoundedView.clipsToBounds = false
    contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
    contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

This way the shadow will be drawn when the view gets initialised and never again after

Comment: Thanks ! but the `awakeFromNib` wast the correct solution.